# Scriptures that are explicitly dedicated for mantras

Tags: scripture, mantras

In Hinduism, there are different types of scriptures based on their nature.

Most of the scriptures consist of more about a particular aspect and cover other aspects of Hinduism partially.

Suppose if we consider Mahabharata, it contains about yoga, mantra, etc.. But scriptures like Patanjali yoga sutras, hatha yoga prathipadika, etc., are almost completely dedicated to yoga.

Similarly, there are many other scriptures containing mantras. But my doubt is whether are there any scriptures that are completely dedicated to the field of mantra? If yes, then what are the names of the scriptures?

Comment: May be Strotra Ratnavali by Gita Press..

Answer (score 1):

The [Prapañcasāra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/prapancasara) by Śrī Śaṅkara is devoted to the science of mantras, also known as [Mantraśāstra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/mantrashastra). There are several published editions including commentaries, elaborating on the subject of the science of mantras. Supposedly, Śaṅkara composed this work as a summary of an older and vaster compendium of Tantra.

First, the commentary by his Śaṅkara’s disciple, Padmapādācārya (8th century) including a sub-commentary. The elaborate introduction is available [in English on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Prapanchasara.Tantra.of.Adi.Shankaracharya.with.Vivarana.and.Vritti_201510/page/n17/mode/2up) and includes a summary of all chapters.

Another edition includes the commentary called [Prapañcasārasāra Saṅgraha](https://archive.org/details/PrapanchaSarasaraSangrahaOfGirivanendraSaraswathi/page/n3/mode/2up) (16th or 17the century). From the preface:

> In this volume we publish the work entitled Prapañchasārasāra Saṅgraha of Geervanendra Saraswathi. It is fairly a big work consisting of 15,000 granthas, and hence we are publishing it in two Parts. Sri Sankara, the great Philosopher wrote Prapanchasara, a work on Mantra Sastra. The present work is an elaboration of the subject of Prapanchasara and hence is styled Prapanchasarasara Sangraha.

Another work on Mantraśāstra is the Śāradātilaka-tantra: composed, probably in the twelfth century, by Lakṣmaṇadeśika [(source)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-school-of-oriental-and-african-studies/article/saradatilakatantra-on-yoga-a-new-edition-and-translation-of-chapter-25/65682490D8D1EFE256AEEE5655736EC4). It is available on [archive.org in Sanskrit](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.282765) (includes commentaries, 1000+ pages) and a translation of the 25th chapter is posted on [acamedia](https://www.academia.edu/11799357/The_%C5%9A%C4%81rad%C4%81tilakatantra_on_Yoga_A_New_Edition_and_Translation_of_Chapter_25). An English translation of the root text is also available under ISBN 8170301750.

Mantra Śāstra is common to all the traditions including Śāktā, Vaiśnava, Śaiva, Śrauta and Bauddha. ([source](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sri_Vidya)) The texts suchs as Mantramahodadhi and Mantramahārṇava are mentioned as well.

For more literature regarding Mantraśāstra, see [chapter VII of “A history of Indian Literature” Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/AHistoryOfIndianLiteratureVolIIFasc.2HinduTantricAndShaktaLiteratureJGonda/page/n137/mode/2up).